# Ember.js tests failure due to PhantomJS syntax error

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs, syntax-error, ember-testing

I'm getting this error when running my tests in an Ember application. Apparently there's a syntax error (`Unexpected token ','`) that is occurring in a way that makes the very loading of the test environment fail, therefore it consequently makes every single test fails.

```
$ ember test
version: 1.13.13
Built project successfully. Stored in "/Users/ernesto/code/projects/my-app/frontend/tmp/class-tests_dist-cqvfx9XF.tmp".
not ok 1 PhantomJS 2.0 - global failure
    ---
        actual: >
            null
        message: >
            SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','
        Log: |
    ...
not ok 2 PhantomJS 2.0 - global failure
    ---
        actual: >
            null
        message: >
            Error: Could not find module `frontend/config/environment` imported from `frontend/tests/helpers/resolver`
        Log: |
    ...
not ok 3 PhantomJS 2.0 - global failure
    ---
        actual: >
            null
        message: >
            Error: Assertion Failed: The tests file was not loaded. Make sure your tests index.html includes "assets/tests.js".
        Log: |
    ...
not ok 4 PhantomJS 2.0 - Integration | Component | dropdown filter: it renders all given options and the empty option
    ---
        actual: >
            null
        message: >
            Promise rejected before it renders all given options and the empty option: you must set a resolver with `testResolver.set(resolver)`
        Log: |
    ...
```

Notice the first error above, that says `global failure` and then reports the unexpected comma token. After that, all remaining tests fail, either because they cannot import a file that exists, or because the `testResolver` is not set, or something else.

The thing is everything runs correctly in the browser. It appears that this has to do with PhantomJS being more strict with some syntax somewhere. But there's no indication in the error message about where this rogue comma is located.

Can someone give me some hints about how to find this comma or solve this error somehow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might think that I could take a look at the diff of the commit that introduced the error. Well, it results to be a merge commit. And the error does not happen on any of the two merged branches before the merge. It only happens after the merge of one of these branches into the other. And there were no conflicts at all during the merge, where a syntax error could have been introduced. And even if it were, the error is not manifesting itself in the browser in development mode, just when running the tests.

Comment: Run some ES5 syntax checker to find the error.

Comment: I'm afraid I use too many ES6 features, so a ES5 syntax checker would go nuts with my code. Or not? Am I missing something?

Comment: The error is that a module was not found. The comma thing might be a red herring

Comment: Not really, the module is there, and from then on, every single test fails because it cannot find any of the modules it imports. And all those modules are there. That's why I said that this initial error (which is also labelled as `global failure` unlike the last of the four in the output above) seems to be the cause of everything else failing. The output above is just the initial four of over 100 errors of every single test in my ember app. And like I said, all those modules reported as not found are there, and haven't been moved or even modified recently.

Comment: The thing is, I find it amazing how can this test can say there's a "global failure" because of an "unexpected token", and not say where this unexpected token is located in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PhantomJS throws a syntax error when an object has duplicate property names, eg:

```
var object = { foo: 1, foo: 2 };
```

Most browsers don't view this as a syntax error and just use the last property definition.